# Sticky header to relative parent with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I've seen variations of this problem everywhere but none seem to solve my problem. I have a tall page that already has a Y scrollbar due to content. Part of the content is a `div style="position: relative;"`, let's call it Div1. `Div1` has content in it causing an X and Y scrollbar. In `Div1` let's say I have a table with so many columns that it's causing the X overflow and so many rows that it's causing the Y overflow of `Div1`.

Is there any way to make the tables header row stick to the top of and maintain it's width in `Div1`?

Imagine the structure like so:

```
<div id="MainPageDiv">
    //OnScreenContent
    //OnScreenContent
    //OnScreenContent
    //OnScreenContent
    <div class=outerDiv>
        <table class="innerTable">
            <thead>
                //thead columns
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                //tbody rows
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    //OnScreenContent
    //OnScreenContent
    //OnScreenContent
    //OFFScreenContent
    //OFFScreenContent
    //OFFScreenContent
</div>
```

So the outerDiv and table sit a little ways down from the top of the page. Also note there is OFFscreenContent farther down.

I want the main page to scroll like normal, but within the outerDiv section I want the thead to stay at the top of the outerDiv container when I scroll in outerDiv.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code so we can figure out together how to solve the issue

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using CSS and jQuery to get the desired result. In my wrapper class I used `position: relative` and on the table header I made it's position `absolute` and on the wrappers scroll event I adjusted the `top` value to whatever the `scrollTop()` of the wrapper was.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outerDiv {
  overflow:scroll;
  height:140px;
}
thead {
 position:absolute;
  top:0; 
}
tbody {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <table class="innerTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

There are two ways you can achieve this

1. set overflow:scroll; on parent element of table.
2. You can use Bootstrap inbuilt **table-responsive** class here. 
   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: That does not address the problem. The table is created fine. I need the Header Row of the table to be stuck to the parent div, but not the grandparent div (outermost div)

Comment: @toadfromgrove Actually it does for me. I have updated the answer with some code for better clarification. I can't help you much if you don't provide your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: edited to reflect structure. Your solution works if that's the only content on the page, but this section of content sits around the middle and has a scrollbar of its own separate of the main page scrollbar.

Comment: @toadfromgrove idea stays the same for this container irrespective of where you put it. However, to see the effects of other elements on this container, we will need to look into the full CSS and surrounding content.

Comment: but I threw your solution on the page and when I set top: 0 it puts it at the top of the main page. it breaks out of the outerDiv container. Structure aside, position: absolute and top: 0 always goes outside it's container and puts the item at the top of the screen